# Empty log file while using logkeys?

Tags: 13.10, log

I have seen various question of this kind but solutions are not working for me, I am currently using Ubuntu 13.10.

I've done:

```
touch test.log
sudo logkeys -s -o test.log 
tail --follow test.log
```

Still, I am getting an empty log file, can anybody help me to resolve this issue?